# How to use async await in React component

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have a component like below

```
import Axios from 'axios';

export const getCountry = async () => dispatch => {
  return await Axios.get('')
  .then(response => {
       //some code
  })
   .catch(error => {
     //some code
  });
};

export default { getCountry };
```

I am getting error `Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`.

Comment: It's because you don't have `async` for the function, it must be before `dispatch`, and then `dispatch` should be wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: Try this `export const getCountry =  () => async (dispatch) => { ... }`

Comment: Thanks @zerkms. Your solution is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import Axios from 'axios';

export const getCountry = async (dispatch) => await Axios.get('...');
```

No need to re-export the same constant.

Comment: `return` not needed ?

Comment: This is equivalent to `getCountry = dispatch => Axios.get('...')` (because `await` will turn a promise into a value, and `async` will make it a promise again).

Comment: @abuabu arrow functions with a single expression can omit the curly brackets and the `return`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body

Comment: @Amadan, But in your answer you used `await`. Thanks.

Comment: I did — because I assumed "some code" is something you wanted. This answer (in this form) does not have space for "some code". Look at it this way: to give a present with a card, you buy a present, unwrap it, put a nice card in, wrap it, give it. To give a present _without_ a card, you could buy a present, unwrap it, _not_ put a card in, wrap it.... or you could just buy a present and give it, skipping the whole wrapping/unwrapping business.

Comment: Using `async` and `await` is pointless here. It's the Nested Promise anti pattern. http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/

Comment: @Quentin I agree that the async/await is unnecessary (although I don't see that's an anti pattern). However, the original code is clearly missing some pieces (e.g. what the dispatch var needs for?). So, I simply "translated" what the user posted in a shorter form.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty much equivalent to:

```
const theFunction = dispatch => {
  return await Axios.get('')
  .then(response => {
       //some code
  })
   .catch(error => {
     //some code
  });
};

export const getCountry = async () => theFunction;
```

I.e. you have an async function that returns a promise of a non-async function. There are several problems here:

- You want `getCountry` to return a country, presumably, not another function;
- You don't need to have a function returning a function (with no closure) be `async`);
- You use `await` uselessly; your code is not more readable, as you still use the promise pattern (not critical);
- You *do* need `theFunction`, a function containing `await`, to be `async` (the immediate source of your error).

The fix is rather easy: get rid of the useless wrapper, and make the correct function `async`:

```
export const getCountry = async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await Axios.get('')
    //some code
  } catch (error) {
    //some code
  }
};
```

EDIT: If your question is in context of [redux-thunk](/questions/tagged/redux-thunk), then my point #1 does not apply; the function would *probably* look like this, instead (NB: I am not familiar with redux-thunk, so this is a guess; you should tag correctly in order to attract the relevant crowd):

```
export const getCountry = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await Axios.get('')
    //some code
  } catch (error) {
    //some code
  }
};
```

Comment: Why you and the other answer removed the outer function? "get rid of the useless wrapper" --- how do you know it's useless?

Comment: @zerkms: because I believe it to be an artifact of the misunderstanding about how `async` is used. See my point #1.

Comment: @Amadan the extra function is very likely deliberate, as this code appears to be an action creator for a thunk. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: @NicholasTower I see. [tag:redux-thunk] tag was not listed, and I was not aware of its existence, going by function name only. I will modify the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example on how to use Async Await with react Hooks

```js
        function useAsyncAwaitHook(searchBook) {
        const [result, setResult] = React.useState([]);
        const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState("false");

        React.useEffect(() => {
            async function fetchBookList() {
            try {
                setLoading("true");
                const response = await fetch(
                `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${searchBook}`
                );

                const jsonData = await response.jsonData();
                // console.log(jsonData);
                setResult(
                jsonData.items.map(item => {
                    console.log(item.volumeInfo.title);
                    return item.volumeInfo.title;
                })
                );
            } catch (error) {
                setLoading("null");
            }
            }

            if (searchBook !== "") {
            fetchBookList();
            }
        }, [searchBook]);

        return [result, loading];
        }
```